# Enabling webcache in WkWebview using WkWebView only(not with the help of NSURLRequest or NSURLSession)

Tags: ios, caching, browser-cache, wkwebview, offline-caching

I know I can enable caching with NSURLRequest

```
  if reachability.isReachable {
             urlRequestCache=NSURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.UseProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10)
        }
        else {
            urlRequestCache = NSURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReturnCacheDataElseLoad, timeoutInterval: 60)
        }
       theWebView.loadRequest(urlRequestCache)
```

But I couldn't find any way directly on WkWebView to achieve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cache for WKWebView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30864893/cache-for-wkwebview)

Comment: @Vizllx - That question is about NSURLRequest or NSURLSession accompanied with WkWebView.But My question is how to achieve by just using the WkWebView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Swift 4:**

```
var webView = WKWebView()
if let url = URL(string: string) {
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.cachePolicy = .returnCacheDataElseLoad
        webView.load(request)
}
```